# How to disable message count badges in Thunderbird 115?

Tags: thunderbird

I somehow enabled the message count but now I do not find the option to disable it again:

[image: Thunderbird badges email count]

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

At the top of left pane, click on the three dots, and uncheck “Show Total Message Count”

[image: Thunderbird 115 left pane]

Comment: I had the Folder Pane Header hidden! That's why I could never find it. Thank you. 

Comment: Show the "Folder Pane Header" again by > View > Folders > Folder Pane Header